# Calling a Custom Java Class in JRuby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jar, jruby

I'm having trouble trying to call a custom java class with JRuby:

"uninitialized constant Classifier::SentimentClassifier"

```
require 'java'
require 'lib/SentimentClassifier.jar'

class Classifier 
    def self.classify
       classifier = SentimentClassifier.new
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between a class being available to jRuby, and actively importing it into your program - see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby.

`require 'lib/SentimentClassifier.jar'` tells jRuby that you want to make the contents of that jar available to your program, but it doesn't import any classes itself.

It's the same in Java - adding a jar to your program's classpath is not the same as importing one of its classes (in fact it's a prerequisite - you can't import a class that isn't on the classpath).

You need to `java_import` the fully-qualified name of your class:

```
require 'java'
require 'lib/SentimentClassifier.jar'
java_import 'com.yourpackage.SentimentClassifier';


class Classifier 
    def self.classify
       classifier = SentimentClassifier.new
    end
end
```

Comment: You can also refer to the fully-qualified name if you don't want to import the Java class: `com.yourpackage.SentimentClassifier.new` or `Java::ComYourpackage::SentimentClassifier.new`